# `nginx -t` does not know path of my nginx conf file

Tags: nginx

I've changed the path of nginx.conf file, and I meet error when run `nginx-t` as below:

```
nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] open() "/etc/nginx/conf/nginx.conf" failed (2: No such file or directory)
```

How to configure nginx with the right real-in-use path of `nginx.conf`?

Thank you very much!

Comment: do you build nginx manually?

Comment: Adding the `-c` for `-t` may work, meanwhile, write the `ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -c /opt/nginx_agent/conf/nginx.conf` in `nginx.service` file may help. However, the default path is not yet configured.

Comment: @nothinux, I don't know how the nginx installed. That's trivial i think.

Comment: can you add output from `nginx -V` and add it to your question? @sonictl